# Moving Chrome saved passwords to Brave browser

Tags: sync, chrome-for-android, password, brave-browser

Is it possible in any way to replicate Chrome passwords to other Chromium-based browsers such as Brave? I have a rooted device. I tried copying the "Login Data" file from the Chrome data folder to the Brave data directory. But Brave didn't pick it. And there is no option to import CSV passwords in Brave browser.

The desktop version of the Brave browser has an option to import CSV passwords, and I did that, but there is no option to sync passwords between the desktop version and the Android browser.

Answer (score 2):

Reading Brave support page it seems that you need to

1. install brave on your desktop machine
2. Import your chrome profile https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019782291-How-do-I-import-or-export-browsing-data-
3. Sync your android phone with brave installed on your desktop. https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021218111-How-do-I-set-up-Sync-

Answer (score 1):

So far, not yet. The Brave Dev team said it's on the roadmap, there are several overlapping issues (with sync, bookmarks, general browser data and specific password import/sync) but there has been no feedback from the Devs on an implementation timeline. Very frustrating. Brave is a great browser and has lots of potential, but if it's to compete with the other browsers it has to include basic features that users expect. Password sync, or at least import and export on mobile/laptop/desktop, is one of them. Payment, Address and other browser data would actually make it comparable to other browsers...